# How to restart a function that is running inside a QThread

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt5, qthread

I am trying to build a Player using `opencv` and `pyqt5`.
I am stuck in a point where i have to change the MediaFile and restart playing again.
I have implemented these logic in a Class called `VideoPlayer`. Heres the code:

```
class VideoPlayer(QObject):
    change_pixmap_signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)
    path = None
    interrupted = False

    def play(self):
        frameNum = 0
        # capture from web cam
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.path)
        self.interrupted = False
        print("Playing Media: {}".format(self.path))

        while True:
            ret, cv_img = cap.read()
            if ret:
                print("Frame: {}".format(frameNum))
                self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(cv_img)
            
            if self.interrupted:
                print("Player Interrupted")
                break

            frameNum = frameNum + 1
```

I am using a moveToThread function to move the object to a thread like so:

```
 self.player = VideoPlayer()
 self.player.path =  FOLDER_DIR + "/" + self.videolists.currentItem().text()
 self.player.change_pixmap_signal.connect(self.update_image)

 self.playerThread = QThread(self)
 self.player.moveToThread(self.playerThread)
 self.playerThread.started.connect(self.player.play)
 self.playerThread.start()
```

Now when a user select a different file I try to restart the player so that it can play the new file selected by the user.

```
def playFile(self):
        if self.playerThread.isRunning():
            print("Thread Status: running")
        self.player.path = FOLDER_DIR + "/" + self.videolists.currentItem().text()
        self.player.interrupted = True
        self.playerThread.start()
```

But the new video doesnot play. Can you help me find what i am doing wrong?

Here is the full code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QGridLayout, QListWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import sys
import cv2
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, Qt, QThread, QObject
import numpy as np
import os
import sys




FOLDER_DIR = #path to folder containing some videos

class VideoPlayer(QObject):
    change_pixmap_signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)
    path = None
    interrupted = False

    def play(self):
        frameNum = 0
        # capture from web cam
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.path)
        self.interrupted = False
        print("Playing Media: {}".format(self.path))

        while True:
            ret, cv_img = cap.read()
            if ret:
                print("Frame: {}".format(frameNum))
                self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(cv_img)
            
            if self.interrupted:
                print("Player Interrupted")
                break

            frameNum = frameNum + 1


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Qt live label demo")
        self.displyWidth = 1280
        self.displayHeight = 720
        # create the label that holds the image
        self.frameLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.frameLabel.resize(self.displyWidth, self.displayHeight)
        # create a text label
        self.textLabel = QLabel('Video')   

        self.classlists = QListWidget()

        self.videolists = QListWidget()
        for i, video in enumerate(os.listdir(FOLDER_DIR)):
            if (video.endswith(".mp4") or video.endswith(".h264")):
                self.videolists.insertItem(i, video)
        self.videolists.setCurrentRow(1)
        self.videolists.clicked.connect(self.playFile)


        # create a Grid layout and add the two labels
        glayout = QGridLayout()
        glayout.addWidget(self.frameLabel,0,0)
        glayout.addWidget(self.textLabel,1,0)
        glayout.addWidget(self.videolists,0,1)
        glayout.addWidget(self.classlists,1,1)
        # set the glayout as the widgets layout
        self.setLayout(glayout)

        self.player = VideoPlayer()
        self.player.path =  FOLDER_DIR + "/" + self.videolists.currentItem().text()
        self.player.change_pixmap_signal.connect(self.update_image)

        self.playerThread = QThread(self)
        self.player.moveToThread(self.playerThread)
        self.playerThread.started.connect(self.player.play)
        self.playerThread.start()


    def playFile(self):
        if self.playerThread.isRunning():
            print("Thread Status: running")
        self.player.path = FOLDER_DIR + "/" + self.videolists.currentItem().text()
        self.player.interrupted = True
        self.playerThread.start()
        

    @pyqtSlot(np.ndarray)
    def update_image(self, cv_img):
        """Updates the frameLabel with a new opencv image"""
        qt_img = self.convert_cv_qt(cv_img)
        self.frameLabel.setPixmap(qt_img)
    
    def convert_cv_qt(self, cv_img):
        """Convert from an opencv image to QPixmap"""
        rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        h, w, ch = rgb_image.shape
        bytes_per_line = ch * w
        convert_to_Qt_format = QtGui.QImage(rgb_image.data, w, h, bytes_per_line, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        p = convert_to_Qt_format.scaled( self.displyWidth, self.displayHeight, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        return QPixmap.fromImage(p)
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = App()
    a.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Qt has its own media reading facilities. you should use those instead. OpenCV is not made for handling media files even though it has some convenience functions for that. it's made for computer vision.

Comment: Yes i am planning to build a video annotation tool for my computer vision project using opencv. Thats why its a requirement that I use opencv to handle the media files. Thank you.

Comment: you should use Qt for any media handling... you can always convert every single frame to a numpy array to process with OpenCV.

Comment: Setting the flag alone is not enough, as the thread is still running at that point, and as the [`start()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#start) documentation explains: "If the thread is already running, this function does nothing.". Add `self.playerThread.quit()` and `self.playerThread.wait()` before restarting it. You should also change the path *after* stopping the thread (or at least, after setting the `interrupted` flag), not before.

Comment: @musicamante, sorry to bother again I was searching about this same question but didnt find anything relevant, when you have time could you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76353484/pyqt-how-to-restart-a-function-that-is-running-inside-a-qthread, , cheers P.