# PyQt How to restart a Worker that is running inside a QThread

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

Title is similat to this : [How to restart a function that is running inside a QThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71407687/how-to-restart-a-function-that-is-running-inside-a-qthread) but since there is no answer I'll ask with my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QGridLayout,
    QWidget,
)

import sys
import time


class AThread(QThread):
    restart_worker = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(AThread, self).__init__()


    def restarted(self):
        
        self.restart_worker.emit()


class Go(QMainWindow):
    custom_signal = pyqtSignal(str)
    button_signal = pyqtSignal(str, str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        
        
        self.control =  {'break': False} # dict with your control variable
        
        self.flag = 'off'
        
        self.setupUi()
        
        print('runing Main  on Qthread : ' , int(QThread.currentThreadId()) )
        
    def setupUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Main GUI")
        self.resize(300, 250)
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        
        # self.thread = QThread()
        
        self.thread = AThread()

        self.worker = Worker(self.control, self.flag) 
        
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        
        self.label_thread_worker = QLabel("thread_worker: 0")
        
        self.start_thread_worker_button = QPushButton("start_thread_worker", self)
        
        self.flag_var_button = QPushButton("flag_is_variable", self)
        
        self.flag_var_button.setDisabled(True)
        
        self.flag_dict_button = QPushButton("flag_is_dict", self)
        
        self.flag_dict_button.setDisabled(True)
        
        # self.start_thread_worker_button.clicked.connect(self.thread.start)
        
        self.thread.restart_worker.connect(self.worker.run)
        
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        
        self.start_thread_worker_button.clicked.connect(self.thread_start)
        
        self.worker.progress.connect(self.reportProgress)
        
        self.flag_dict_button.clicked.connect(self.change_flag_dict)
        
        self.flag_var_button.clicked.connect(self.change_flag_var)
        
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.stop)
        
        # Set the layout
        layout = QGridLayout()     
        layout.addWidget(self.label_thread_worker, 2, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.start_thread_worker_button, 2, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.flag_var_button, 3,2)        
        layout.addWidget(self.flag_dict_button, 4,2)        
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
    
    
    def thread_start(self):
        
        print('self.thread.isRunning() :', self.thread.isRunning())
        if self.thread.isRunning() == False:
            
            self.thread.start()
            print('self.thread.isRunning() :', self.thread.isRunning())
            
        else:
            
            self.thread.restarted()
            
            self.thread.start()            
            
    
    def reportProgress(self, n):
        self.label_thread_worker.setText(f"thread_worker: {n}")
        
        self.start_thread_worker_button.setDisabled(1)
        
        self.flag_var_button.setDisabled(0)
        
        self.flag_dict_button.setDisabled(0)
        
    def change_flag_dict(self):
        self.control['break'] = True
        
    def change_flag_var(self):
        self.flag = 'on'
        print('self.flag = ', self.flag)
    
    
    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def stop(self, sentence):
        print('stopping worker with : ', sentence)
        
        self.label_thread_worker.setText("thread_worker: 0")
        self.start_thread_worker_button.setEnabled(1)
        
        self.flag_var_button.setDisabled(True)
        
        self.flag_dict_button.setDisabled(True)
        
        
        self.control['break'] = False
        
        # self.close()
        
   
class Worker(QObject):
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)
    
    finished = pyqtSignal(str)
    
    
    def __init__(self, ctrl, flag, parent=None):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(parent)
             
        self.control = ctrl
        self.flag = flag 
        self.sentence = ''
    
    
    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
               
        print('running worker on Qthread : ' , int(QThread.currentThreadId()) )
        
        self.cnt = 0
        while True:
            
            time.sleep(1)
            
            self.cnt += 1
            
            self.progress.emit(self.cnt)
            
            # print(self.flag)
            
            if self.control['break'] == True:
                
                self.sentence = 'flag_is_dict'
                
                break
            
            if self.flag == 'on' :
                
                self.sentence = 'flag_is_variable'
                
                break
        
        self.finished.emit(self.sentence)
            
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
     app = QApplication(sys.argv)
     MainApp = Go()
     MainApp.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code was a Minimal Reproducible Example that I wrote to ask another question abouy how/why I can stop a Worker inside a QThread passing a Mutable flag to it but cannot do the same with a simply Variable, I know I read somewhere that this is the way but being naive at Python, I cannot figure out/picture in my mind  why the latter doesn't work like the former. While creating the MRE I realized I wanted to be able to restart my Worker without re-creating a new QThread. Here the problem started. As you can see from my code :

```
def thread_start(self):
        
        print('self.thread.isRunning() :', self.thread.isRunning())
        if self.thread.isRunning() == False:
            
            self.thread.start()
            print('self.thread.isRunning() :', self.thread.isRunning())
            
        else:
            
            self.thread.restarted()
            
            self.thread.start()
```

If I comment out  `self.thread.restarted()` my Worker cannot be restarted anymore.

I though I could call  `self.thread.start()` to have my Worker running again as per

`self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)` but had to end up subcclassing QThread with:

```
class AThread(QThread):
    restart_worker = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(AThread, self).__init__()


    def restarted(self):
        
        self.restart_worker.emit()
```

and using `self.thread.restart_worker.connect(self.worker.run)` in my QMainWindow

**init** toghether with a call to `self.thread.restarted()` [see code above].

Why is that ? What am I doing wrong ?

Code works as follow :

pressing "start_thread_worker" button --> thread_workercounter starts counting

pressing flag_is_variable --> nothing happens (this is my question about mutable flag)

pressing flag_is_dict --->  thread_worker counter stops

I can only restart start_thread_worker using the subclassed QThread with new Signal/Slot
called by `self.thread.restarted()`.

Side note:

`@pyqtSlot()` decorator in `class Worker(QObject):` is not needed for the example to work

Of course using `self.thread = QThread()` with `self.thread.start()` in `def thread_start(self):` wasnt working so I tried with the subclassing.

**EDITED**

Re reading-it looks like a very dumb question !!! How could you start something that is already started ???

So I'll try changing my question in : is it the right/best way to accomplish my desiderata or is something you should not do it and I should reimplement the entire logic of my problem/task

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you think that your thread is not reacting to changing the variable is due to some incorrect assumptions. In python, strings are immutable objects.  Which means that when two variables reference the same string, reassigning one of the variables to a different string will have no effect on the other variable.

So in your main window you assign `self.flag = "off"` and then you pass that variable to your worker and assign the same `str` instance with `self.flag = flag`.  However in your `change_flag_var` method, when you reassign the `self.flag` variable to "on", this has no effect on the `self.flag` variable that belongs to the Worker class.

To demonstrate.

```
>>> flag = "on"
>>> flag2 = flag
>>> flag is flag2
True
>>> flag2
'on'
# Now we reassign flag to "off" and it will have no effect on flag2
>>> flag = "off"
>>> flag
'off'
>>> flag2
'on'
>>> flag is flag2
False
```

This can be further demonstrated by simply changing your `change_flag_var` method to the following example and it will work as you originally expected it too, and actually break the while loop of the worker class.:

```
def change_flag_var(self):
    self.worker.flag = 'on'
    print('self.worker.flag = ', self.worker.flag)
```

---

For the question regarding restarting the worker's run method, I see nothing wrong with the way you have implemented it.  However, at least with this example, personally I would probably just convert the Worker class into a subclass of QThread  and simply spin up a new instance every time the `start_worker_thread_button` is clicked.  For example:

```
class Go(QMainWindow):
    custom_signal = pyqtSignal(str)
    button_signal = pyqtSignal(str, str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi()
        self.flag = "off"
        print('runing Main  on Qthread : ' , int(QThread.currentThreadId()) )

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Main GUI")
        self.resize(300, 250)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_thread_worker = QLabel("thread_worker: 0")
        self.start_thread_worker_button = QPushButton("start_thread_worker", self)
        self.flag_var_button = QPushButton("flag_is_variable", self)
        self.flag_var_button.setDisabled(True)
        self.start_thread_worker_button.clicked.connect(self.thread_start)
        self.flag_var_button.clicked.connect(self.change_flag_var)
        # Set the layout
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label_thread_worker, 2, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.start_thread_worker_button, 2, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.flag_var_button, 3,2)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(layout)


    def thread_start(self):
        self.worker = Worker(self.flag)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.stop)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.worker.progress.connect(self.reportProgress)
        self.worker.start()

    def reportProgress(self, n):
        self.label_thread_worker.setText(f"thread_worker: {n}")
        self.start_thread_worker_button.setDisabled(1)
        self.flag_var_button.setDisabled(0)

    def change_flag_var(self):
        self.worker.flag = 'on'
        print('self.flag = ', self.worker.flag)

    def stop(self):
        self.label_thread_worker.setText("thread_worker: 0")
        self.start_thread_worker_button.setEnabled(1)
        self.flag_var_button.setDisabled(True)


class Worker(QThread):
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, flag, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.flag = flag
        self.sentence = ''

    def run(self):
        print('running worker on Qthread : ' , int(QThread.currentThreadId()) )
        self.cnt = 0
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.cnt += 1
            self.progress.emit(self.cnt)
            if self.flag == 'on' :
                self.sentence = 'flag_is_variable'
                break
```

Comment: Thanks, I was also thinking about just use self.thread.quit() , self.thread.wait() and then self.thread.start() that now should work